# File was uploaded, but it is not shown on media section of the dashboard

Tags: attachments, user-registration, uploads

I managed to add an upload field to the user registration form of the website I'm building. I, also, was able to handle the upload. 
However, despite the file was correctly copied to the ***uploads*** folder, the ***Media*** section of the ***Admin Dashboard*** is still empty. 
Here is the code so far:

```
function handle_upload($user_id){
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    }

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['logo'];

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

    if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'logo', $movefile['url']);
    } else {
        /**
         * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
         */
        echo $movefile['error'];
    }
}
```

How can I fix it? How can I associate the *user_id* to the newly attached file?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I modified the function, by adding the *wp_insert_attachment* function:

```
function handle_upload($user_id){
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    }

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['logo'];

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

    // // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $movefile['url'], 
        'post_mime_type' => $uploadedfile['type'],
        'post_title'     => $uploadedfile['name'],
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    // Insert the attachment.
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $movefile['url'], $user_id );

    if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'logo', $movefile['url']);
    } else {
        /**
         * Error generated by _wp_handle_upload()
         */
        echo $movefile['error'];
    }
}
```

But I get this error message: `WordPress database error: [Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (mydb.wp_posts, CONSTRAINT author_id FOREIGN KEY (post_author) REFERENCES wp_users (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)]`

Do I have to specify a *post_id*?

Comment: https://tommcfarlin.com/upload-files-in-wordpress/

Comment: it's the normal function of `wp_handle_upload`. to add the file in the medias, use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but those functions allow to link a post to an attachment. Is there a function that allows to link that file to a user? Thanks

Comment: The only association files have with users in WordPress is the author. You can set the author of an upload by setting the `post_author` in the `$post_data` argument for `media_handle_upload`. Keep in mind that in WordPress code media in the media library is referred to as 'attachments', but they don't need to be attached to posts.

Comment: I updated the question.